# Passing custom variables/parameters to jenkins job by github pull requester builder comments

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have to pass few varibles to the jenkins job from the GITHUB pull request. I am using github pull request builder and is there any way i can pass some varible values to jenkins when I create a pull request?

Comment: did you try https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin?